# PowerShell Where-Object doesn't work for Get-AzureRMRouteTable. Returns all objects still

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

```
Get-AzureRMRouteTable |Where-Object { ($_.Name -like '*why*')}
```

I have 3 UDRs with the names `why`, `bye`, and `123455`

Why does this cmldet return ALL of them?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5518). And the request has been [fixed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/commit/51678e78d39195dcb37792dd7391c543c7464bca). Update the PowerShell module [AzureRM 6.5.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/6.5.0) to fix this issue.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion 6.5.0
```

Comment: Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a Resource Group

Comment: Regardless, without a resource group 
    Get-AzureRmRouteTable already returns all tables. Why wouldn't it use Where-Object?

Comment: It's a known issue, please see my update and accept it as an answer so others who might find the same scenario might help..

Comment: I've updated my Powershell AzureRm Modules and it works without a resource group.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have updated my reply hope this can help others.